# Two different papers with the same title, how to split them up in Google Scholar

Tags: citations, titles

A friend of mine ended up in a weird situation that they're looking for advice about: they published two different papers under identical titles. Google Scholar lists both papers with the same number of citations, and with the citations listed being the combined list for both papers.

What should they do? One solution might be to change slightly one the titles. They might do this by adding "a review" at the end of one of the papers, as it is a review paper. Are there better ideas?

Comment: Google scholar is the least of your friend's worries. This will cause all kinds of confusion. If the title can be changed--which means the paper is not really published--then yes, they should change it ASAP.

Comment: Has anyone tried to delete articles from Google Scholar and add them again - as suggested  ? - What about the titles - in my friend's case these are identical but all the other details are different. 
.
The review paper (2017) has no citations yet, but the research/journal paper (2014) has already got 5 citations. Google Scholar lista the papers one after the other with the same number of citations but the review paper got this number stricken through.
Is there any risk involved in deleting both items and adding them again ?

Comment: No risk in deleting and adding them again, but the same problem might persist.